# "TypeError: data type not understood" while reading csv file

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, csv, numpy

I am attempting to read a .csv file and assign a particular range of values to its own list for indexing purposes:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib as plot
import pandas as pd

# read in the data held in the csv file using "read_csv", a function built into the "pandas" module
Ne = pd.read_table('Ionosphere_data.csv', sep='\s+', dtype=np.float64);

print(Ne.shape)
print(np.dtype)

# store each dimension from the csv file into its own array for plotting use
Altitude = Ne[:,1];
Time = Ne[0,:];

# loop through each electron density value with respect to

Ne_max = []

for i in range(0,len(Time)):
  for j in range(0,len(Altitude)):
    Ne_max[j] = np.max(Ne[:,i]);

print Ne_max

#plot(Time,Altitude,Ne_max);
#xaxislabel('Time (hours)')
#yaxislabel('Altitude (km)')
```

however when I run this code, ipython displays the error message:
"TypeError: data type not understood" in context to line 10. (Another side note, when 'print(np.dtype)' is not included, a separate error message is given to line 13: "TypeError: unhashable type"). 
Does anyone know if I am reading in the file incorrectly or if there is another problem?

Comment: Should that be `print(Ne.dtype)`?

Comment: Should actually be print(np.dtype(Ne))

Comment: No, that won't work.  When you call `np.dtype(obj)`, it tries to *convert* `obj` to a numpy dtype.  If you want to inspect the data types of your Pandas DataFrame, use `Ne.dtypes` (it is an attribute of the DataFrame object).

Comment: interesting note! thanks for that; it appears that my confusion with trying this out came from attempting the command "print(Ne.dtype)" instead of "print(Ne.dtypes)"

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, you say that the line

```
print(np.dtype)
```

should be

```
print(np.dtype(Ne))
```

That gives the error `TypeError: data type not understood`.  [`numpy.dtype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html) tries to *convert* its argument into a numpy data type object.  It is not used to inspect the data type of the argument.

For a Pandas DataFrame, use the `dtypes` attribute:

```
print(Ne.dtypes)
```

Comment: Thanks, that clears up the datatype issue. I still can't seem to solve my other issue in that running this program dishes out an error message to line 13 saying "TypeError: Unhashable Type"

Comment: It is simpler if you ask one question at a time. Start a new question about that issue.